# Stopping user input using the enter key in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, fgets

I'm trying to write a program that receives strings using fgets, but for some reason I can't get it to go past the user input stage. The input should stop once the user enters a "blank line", ie. the Enter key (\n) but even when this key is pressed the loop continues.

Here's the problematic part of my code:

```
char array[100][256];
for (int i = 0; array[i] != '\n'; i++)
{
    fgets(array[i], 256, stdin);
}
```

100 and 256 represent the maximum amount of lines and chars expected respectively.

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: `array` is uninitialised, but you immediately check it's not `\n`, so undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hint: compile with warnings enabled...

Comment: @FlorentSebag That had to read `array[i-1][0] != '\n'`, which is obviously problematic in the first iteration

Comment: You need to do a first fgets before your loop then change your condition to put this : `for (int i = 0; array[i][0] != '\n'; i++)`

Comment: Anyway, this is a poorly scalable design, and some embedded machines might not even be able to allocate 26 kB of data on the stack. Once you are sure you can initialise/use variables correctly, you should consider using dynamic arrays - or, far better, some library that will already safely "receive strings" for you, so you won't have to reinvent that wheel for the millionth time.

Comment: @underscore_d While you are correct on a professional level, you should consider that this is a question of a hobby programmer, which tries to solve a problem on his own (and maybe in a (working) way, which is suboptimal for embedded machines)

Comment: In C, there are three kinds of loops: "for", "while" and "do...while". The third kind of loop is appropriate if you want the loop to run at least once.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel but that won't save you from uninitialised memory and resulting UB.

Comment: @underscore_d In this case, it could, because the read access to the uninitialized array takes place in the `for` conditional clause before entering the loop, while the condition is checked _after_ the first iteration in a "do...while" loop. You have to use it correctly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code fixed with minimal changes, explanations in comments. Note that this is not a very good way to solve your problem, long lines for example may not behave as you want (they will get split at several `array` lines).

```c
char array[100][256];
memset(array, 0, sizeof array); // initialize the memory
int i = 0;
while(i<100) // avoid overflow of lines, also while may be clearer than for loop
{
    if(!fgets(array[i], 256, stdin)) break; // detect read failure
    if(array[i][0] == '\n') break; // got empty line
    // Note [0] above to test first char of line i
    ++i;
}
if (i==100) { /* too many lines */ }
else if (array[i][0] == 0) { /* read failure */  }
else {  /* indexes 0...i-1 contain data, index i contains empty line */ }
```

Comment: `if (i==100) ` -- `i` will be out of scope when you get there with the scope of `i` limited to the loop above. (move the declaration of `i` out of the loop declaration, maybe?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah yeah. I turned the whole loop into `while`, while I was at it, I think it is clearer that way.